# Centos fstab how to know what filesystem to put

Tags: partitioning, centos, fstab, centos-7

i have installed centos with default settings, and i'd like to partition my server securely by modifying fstab. Thing is i don't know which filesystem i should put in the fstab file to reference eg. /var or /var/www aren't they all sda1 which is the main disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They might be different partitions on the same disk. It's normal for any linux installer to create multiple partitions.

<s>Changing the partitioning scheme in fstab won't make your server any more secure</s>, I would recommend you don't edit it unless you know exactly what you need to change and why.

This [article](http://linuxbsdos.com/2011/09/18/guide-to-disks-and-disk-partitions-in-linux/) explains partitioning in linux pretty well. Just keep in mind GPT is much more common now than when it was written.

**Edited:** striked out false statement.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to follow the centos securing guide, and partitioning was one of the first things on the list.

Comment: Cool, I've actually never seen that done before.